# Will an x86_64 CPU notice that a page-table entry has changed to not-present while setting the dirty flag in the PTE?

Tags: linux-kernel, x86-64, cpu-architecture, tlb, page-tables

There is a scenario as follows:

The pte `a` of PAGE `A` set following field:

- BIT(0) present
- BIT(1) writable
- BIT(M-1,12) page  frame
- dirty flag is *NOT SET*

```
CPU0                                     CPU1
                                         cached translation information 
                                         about the PTE a (TLB)
modify pte a present flags to 0.
(not exec tlb shootdown)                 
                                         write a virtual address translated by pte a
```

Now, will this write operation execute normally or will it cause a page fault?

---

The issue comes from a Linux kernel commit. Based on the code logic of the
commit, I tend to believe that the situation mentioned above can cause page
faults.

Information about this COMMIT:

```
commit d950c9477d51f0cefc2ed3cf76e695d46af0d9c1
Author: Mel Gorman <mgorman@suse.de>
Date:   Fri Sep 4 15:47:35 2015 -0700

    mm: defer flush of writable TLB entries
```

The code is no longer shown here, and the approximate logic is:

When `kswapd` was performing memory reclamation, it was found that a page could
be reclaimed. First, unmap it. The unmap operation will modify the page table
structures After modification, it is necessary to perform a tlb flush (may
execute tlb shootdown) However, the kernel may delay the tlb flush action in
order to perform batch flush (as tlb shootdown requires sending ipi, batch
flush will reduce the number of ipi sent to one). But it needs to be determined
whether the PTE is dirty before the clear PTE,

If it's dirty, you need to flush immediately If it weren't dirty, you can batch
flush it after `page_out()`

I think it may be due to the following reasons:

If the page is dirty, it indicates that someone has recently accessed the page,
and if there is no flush tlb remote, other CPUs may still be able to access it
normally without generating PF. However, if the page is not dirty, after
clearing the pte, even if other CPUs use old tlb to access it (the dirty flag
in old tlb is 0), the dirty flags will be updated and a full check will be made
to generate PF. (The above is my own understanding, I cannot guarantee it is
correct).

---

If modify PTE's dirty bit 1 to 0, but not flush tlb. This situation is
described in Intel SDM

```
If software modifies a paging-structure entry that identifies the final
 physical address for a linear address(either a PTE or a paging-structure
entry in which the PS flag is 1) to change the dirty flag from 1 to 0,
failure to perform an invalidation may result in the processor not setting
 that bit in response to a subsequent write to a linear address whose
translation uses the entry. Software cannot interpret the bit being clear as
an indication that such a write has not occurred
```

But regarding the issue mentioned at the beginning, it was not
found in Intel SDM.

---

Thanks for Peter's testing suggestion. I have written a kernel module based
on the Linux kernel. The testing code is not specifically presented, but the
program flow is as follows(single thread):

> 1. set or clear PTE dirty bit
> 2. flush tlb all
> 3. read the page pointed by this PTE in order to establish new tlb.
> 4. clear P or RW bit of this PTE(after changing PTE, DO NOT flush TLB)
> 5. write the page pointed by this PTE.

The test results are as follows:

1. set dirty, clear present, (set RW) : normally execute
2. set dirty, clear RW(read only), (set present) : normally execute
3. set not dirty, clear present, (set RW) : cause #PF
4. set not dirty, clear RW(read only), (set present) : cause #PF

> NOTE
>
> Set/clear the dirty bit is to set the initial state of TLB

> [my test link](https://github.com/cai-fuqiang/kernel_test/tree/master/tlb_test)

---

According to Peter and prl's answers, it seems that CET will affect the test results But I don't know the details of CET. I do a simple test by using the RDMSR instruction to read IA32_U_CET in the kernel module and this instruction will cause a # GP, does this mean that my CPU does not support the CET function ?

Comment: Does CPU1 start with the PTE cached in its TLB?  If not, then obviously it would page fault.  But if it did, then IDK if the RMW to update the Dirty bit would also result in a new check of the other bits.  (This would probably be the same as a single-core situation where you modify the PTE in memory but don't run `invlpg` or reload CR3; some microarchitectures do some snooping for TLB coherency, but not for changing present to not-present.  https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2015/08/pagewalk-coherence/)

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry.  I forgot to specify the TLB status of CPU 1. As you commented, CPU1 has already cached translation information about pte a (TLB) before CPU 0 modifies it.

Comment: Hello, Peter. It seems that code blocks are not supported in comments. I added an answer below.

Comment: If you're going to post an answer, write it as an answer to the question for future readers, not a reply to me.  As is, it seems like you're guessing at an answer based on some evidence from a Linux kernel change.  If the evidence isn't strong enough for it to be an actual answer, an edit to the *question* is a good place to put more details.

Comment: Thank  for your suggestion. I will integrate the following answers into the question part.

Comment: What hardware did you test on?  It might be interesting to test on some much older hardware from long before the CET feature.   (The older CPUs that can sometimes set the Dirty flag in a PTE without the write bit set might not have been the generation right before CET; they might just have documented it with CET because there wasn't a CPUID feature bit directly associated with the change in TLB / PTE handling.)

Comment: 3. set not dirty, clear present, (set RW) : cause #PF - that is interesting, I wasn't able to replicate this with a test module + QEMU KVM. I kept not seeing any #PF (though I might have done something wrong).

Comment: How are you sure that the entry is still in TLB at the moment of the write and hasn't been removed by the CPU?

Comment: @PeterCordes hello, Peter, I tested on the `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H`

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I tested on host. However, according to the Intel manual, TLB has the same behavior in VMX non root operation and VMX root operation.I will then test the program in a virtual machine launched by KVM. I cannot guarantee that the TLB of this PTE has not been invalidated (the CPU may implicitly invalidate them) . At the software level, it is possible to minimize the cycle between TLB generation and write operations. However, according to "set dirty, clear present, (set RW)", there are no results for cause # PF, indicating that TLB has not been invalidated yet

Comment: @MarcoBonelli But from your testing of the "set not dirty, clear present, set PW" condition, but no # PF results were generated.  I'm not sure if you're doing something wrong or if your CPU is different from mine Please perform the following steps in order:`1. insmod tlb_test.ko  2. echo 1 > /proc/fuqiang/my_page_proc 3. echo 3 > /proc/fuqiang/my_page_misc_proc`

Comment: @MarcoBonelli  hi~ Marco,  I tested  on a virtual machine and the results were the same  on a physical machine

Comment: @wangfuqiang yeah my bad, works as you report and I get a page fault. Interesting then, your initial assumption seems correct. Maybe you can write a self-answer.

Comment: Thanks, Marco. But I still don't know the details of CET or whether it will affect my test results After I confirm, I will write an answer. Thank you very much for your patience in this test  : )

Answer (score 2):

The Intel SDM, volume 3, section 4.8, says:

> If software on one logical processor writes to a page while software
> on another logical processor concurrently clears the R/W flag in the
> paging-structure entry that maps the page, execution on some
> processors may result in the entry’s dirty flag being set (due to the
> write on the first logical processor) and the entry’s R/W flag being
> clear (due to the update to the entry on the second logical
> processor). This will never occur on a processor that supports
> control-flow enforcement technology (CET). Specifically, a processor
> that supports CET will never set the dirty flag in a paging-structure
> entry in which the R/W flag is clear.

Comment: Interesting that it doesn't say anything about what will happen to the store itself (#PF from store to a non-writeable page, or just works but still doesn't set the Dirty bit, like adding extra logic to the microcode-assist atomic RMW to mask the new dirty bit with the inverted R/W bit from memory).  The former mechanism (#PF) would probably also apply for the PTE becoming invalid (not Present), but the documentation only talks about the R/W bit.  Interesting and related but far from definitive.  Probably needs experimental testing.  (On the same core is probably fine and easy to test.)

Comment: @Peter, it cannot write to the page without setting D. That would cause data corruption when the OS discards the contents of the page because it apparently hasn't changed.

Comment: Oh right, that rules out doing the write anyway without setting D.  So on CPUs without CET, would it also be possible for other cores to set the D flag in a PTE with the Present bit cleared, like is possible when clearing the R/W bit?  If so, OSes would have to check D again after invlpg and after hearing back from other cores that a TLB shootdown is complete, if there's a backing-store for this page which has to get its data.

Comment: @Peter, when P is 0, the remaining 63 bits of the PTE are available to software.

Comment: Right, but I thought HW architects might consider it software's fault if they rely on those bits not being modified while other cores still have valid TLB entries caching this PTE.  That seemed like a plausible design.  If it's not the actual design, then that's the answer to the OP's question, along with your point about definitely never allowing writes without setting the Dirty bit.  HW that doesn't require waiting for a reply from TLB shootdowns being complete seems obviously more convenient and efficient for software, so it makes sense, but I wasn't sure it would work this way.

Comment: That note from the SDM doesn't seem to help much. In the case at hand, nobody touches the R/W flag, which stays in the PTE and cached in TLB. The present flag is the one being cleared. As Peter notes, considering multiple CPUs also doesn't seem to matter in this case. The real question is whether HW checks the current present flag in the PTE when trying to set the dirty flag and therefore issues a page fault OR simply relies on the fact that a TLB entry exists and updates the dirty flag without a page fault (meaning that even if P=0 on the PTE, HW will set D=1).

Comment: While it's true that "when P is 0, the remaining 63 bits of the PTE are available to software", when a TLB entry exists that means that for what the HW knows the page is present, so I wouldn't rule out a silent PTE update anyway. After all, again as Peter is saying, it seems like it would be the programmer's fault to not have correctly flushed the TLB in such case. It'd be interesting to find something about this in the SDM vol 3, but I could not find much (mainly looking at sections 4.8 and 4.10).